# Problem getting the value of a tag from dynamic HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having a problem with the Python code getting the value of a dynamic HTML tag.
The function can be seen below.
The tag value must be a number and not a dash.
I've tried several approaches, including using selenium (sample code), but in none of them does the value of the tag, which can be seen directly on the website, appear.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import bs4

def scrape_content_from_dynamic_websites():
    url = "https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/petr4/"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    all_strongs = soup.find_all("strong", {"data-item":"avg_F"})
    driver.close()

    return (all_strongs)

def main09():
    print(scrape_content_from_dynamic_websites())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main09()
```

Result:
[-]

Expected:
[95,81%]

Comment: Dynamic means `JavaScript`. `bs4` is just an HTML parser that can't run `JS`. Either try selenium or see if there's an API.

Comment: Note that I am using selenium in the example and yet the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//strong')` and then get the text from the elements found.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def scrape_content_from_dynamic_websites():
    url = "https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/petr4/"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    elms = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//strong')
    all_strongs = [elem.text for elem in elms]
    driver.close()
    return all_strongs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = scrape_content_from_dynamic_websites()
    print(res)
```

Outputs a list:

```
['', '', '', '36,10', '17,45', '37,16', '20,11', '106,52%', '', 'PETR4', 'IBOV', 'PN', '100 %', '1.670.598.995,66', 'IBOV', '', '7,189', 'OPÇÕES', '1.047', 'FORECAST', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'INDICADORES DE VALUATION', '20,11%', '3,44', '-0,15', '1,22', '2,65', '3,49', '1,72', '2,27', '29,59', '0,46', '10,50', '0,88', '-64,83', '-0,54', 'INDICADORES DE ENDIVIDAMENTO', '0,62', '0,87', '1,15', '0,38', '0,62', '0,95', 'INDICADORES DE EFICIÊNCIA', '51,08%', '50,94%', '38,69%', '25,53%', 'INDICADORES DE RENTABILIDADE', '35,47%', '13,35%', '21,54%', '0,52', 'INDICADORES DE CRESCIMENTO', '17,72%', '-%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '15/12/2023', '0,03', '0,03', '14.729.310', '517.587.953', '2.704', '', '', '16,7786', '7,2539', '56,77%', '0,0000', '56,77%', '-', '-\n()', '-\n(-)', '()', '386.007.000.000', '1.025.496.000.000', '147.311.000.000', '305.451.000.000', '67.147.000.000', '238.304.000.000', '484.916.557.074', '723.220.557.074', '13.044.496.930', 'Nível 2', '63,39%', ' ', 'Petróleo. Gás e Biocombustíveis', 'Petróleo. Gás e Biocombustíveis', 'Exploração. Refino e Distribuição', 'InfoMoney', 'InfoMoney', 'InfoMoney', 'Suno Notícias', '+', '+', '17/05/2023', '867.547', '2.748', '5.807', '858.992', 'quantidade de investidores', 'data base', 'fazendo com que a quantidade fique bem baixa', 'até', 'até', 'até', '', 'Índice Brasil 50', '4.566.445.852', '8,004%', 'Índice MidLarge Cap', '4.566.445.852', '7,388%', 'Ibovespa', '4.566.445.852', '7,189%', 'Índice de Ações com Tag Along Diferenciado', '4.566.445.852', '7,163%', 'Índice Brasil 100', '4.566.445.852', '6,907%', 'Índice de Governança Corporativa Trade', '4.566.445.852', '6,796%', 'Índice Brasil Amplo', '4.566.445.852', '6,492%', 'Índice de Ações com Governança Corporativa Diferenciada', '6.849.668.778', '5,942%', 'Índice Dividendos', '816.746.192', '5,314%', 'Índice Carbono Eficiente', '1.614.506.055', '3,175%', '', '', '', '', 'APP', 'ASSINATURAS', 'BULL', 'FORECAST', 'STATUS INVEST', '', '', '', '']
```

But I would harden your XPATH to select only the data you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

You can use their Ajax API to obtain the average value:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0"
}

# type = 0  # 5Y
# type = 1  # 10Y
# type = 2  # MAX
api_url = (
    "https://statusinvest.com.br/acao/payoutresult?code=petr4&companyid=408&type=0"
)

data = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()
print(data["avg"])
```

Prints:

```
95.81422793719463
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution is much more efficient. I imagine there are other APIs on this same page. It would be very useful for me if I could use them directly instead of scraping the HTML page. How can I get the list of APIs from this site? How did you get this API working? How did you get access to the list of parameters? Is there any application that can describe all the parameters of an API? If you could show me the way, that would help a lot with my solution!

Comment: @RenatoSousa Open the page in Firefox/Chrome, then open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and reload the page. You should see the requests the page is doing there (among them are the Ajax calls).